# Users added to SharePoint group after moving to host-named site collection cannot login

Tags: login, ntlm, host-named

I am a developer who has been tasked to do SharePoint installation and configuration as part of implementing a SharePoint product. I guess you could call me an *"incidental SharePoint admin"*, by which I mean my knowledge of SP is patchy. I've hit an issue that I can't seem to find an answer to no matter how I googled it.

### My scenario:

1. Brand new install of SP2010 Foundation, including SP1, on Windows Server 2008 R2.
2. Installed and configured the product to sit in its own path-based site collection.
3. Added an AD security group (mydomain\myGroup) into a custom SP group, Administrators. Part of the product configuration includes creating custom SP groups.
4. Also added an AD user directly into the Administrators group.
5. Confirmed that both AD user directly added into the Administrators group as well as a user added to the mydomain\myGroup can access the site collection.
6. Using Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite PowerShell cmdlets, moved the path-based site collection to a host-named site collection.

   ```
   Restore-SPSite -Identity "https://myhnsc.portal.domain" -Path "site-backup.bak" -HostHeaderWebApplication "http://server-name"
   ```

   ***Note** that I've only got the one default web application (*:80) with NTLM authentication (besides Central Admin) where the host-named site collection sits.*
7. Enabled host header site schema selection with the following snippet:

   ```
   $svc = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
   $svc.EnableHostHeaderSiteBasedSchemeSelection = $true
   $svc.Update()
   ```
8. The environment uses off-box SSL termination with a reverse proxy which has been configured according to the MSDN documentation at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288637%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section8

### Issue/Problem:

1. Users who were previously added to the Administrators group continue to be able to login and access the site collection.
2. New users added to mydomain\myGroup are able to access the site collection but users added directly to the Administrators group are not able to login. Generates a Microsoft Windows security auditing 4265 event that says `An account failed to log on.` with the following Failure Information:

   ```
   Failure Reason: An Error occured during Logon.
   Status: 0xc0000413
   Sub Status: 0x0
   ```

I did a google for the status code and it appears to indicate this is due to a domain security setting, users do not have "Allowed to Authenticate" permission on the server.

The part I can't puzzle out is, why new users added to Administrators group were able to access the site collection when it was still a path-based site collection while new users added after it was moved to a host-named site collection generates this error.

Hope someone will be able to shed some light on this.